# Laravel 5 multiple table unique validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

For example, I have 2 tables : `sites1` and `sites2`

I need to check that field `url` which is comes from my html form is unique.

Here my validation rule :

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'url' => unique:sites1|unique:sites2'
        ];
    }
```

Unfortunately, this rule applies only for `sites2` table. Is there any possible ways to validate both tables?

Comment: I assume you should code your custom validation rule. Check this out: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: why not have it stored within an array and check it by then? you might want to try [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your validation rule seems ok. Just make sure that both `sites1` and `sites2` table has field name `url` and both in same database.

Your `unique:sites1` rule will be translated into SQL

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `sites1` where `url` = ?
```

While `unique:sites2` rule will be translated into SQL

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `sites2` where `url` = ?
```

See if first SQL does return result. Long URL may result non unique if used with limited index length. It may be better if you could store hash value of URL so you can compare url just by using hash.

Comment: Can you give me any suggestions or example if URL is come in array data type with request, what should i do.

Comment: @Dipen In that case, you need to create custom validation rule.

Answer (score 9):

No need to maintain the same name in two different tables

In laravel 4.2

```
Validator::make(Input::all, [
    'url' => 'unique:site1,your_column_name|unique:site2:your_column_name_2'
]);
```

Laravel 5.*:

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'url' => 'unique:site1,your_column_name|unique:site2:your_column_name_2'
]);
```

Hopefully it's working fine.

Comment: i don't know why but when using colon(:) after **site2** for unique validation gives me error of  `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'soft.users:email' doesn't exist`. But using comma works fine...

Comment: kindly check your second table's column name whether email or not.

Comment: Replace second colon by comma then it will work,   unique:site2:your_column_name_2  =>  unique:site2,your_column_name_2

Answer (score 0):

In the above answer i think you can't use custom error message, you can do in another way just copy the filed in another field for the two checks.

```
 public function validator(array $data)
    {
        $data = ['url2' => $data['email']];

        $rules = [
            'url' => 'unique:sites1',
            'url2' => 'unique:sites2',
        ];

        $messages = [
            'url.unique' => 'url unique in site 1',
            'url2.unique' => 'url unique in site 2',
        ];

        return $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);
    }





  if ($validator->fails()) {
                if(!empty($validator->errors()->get('url2'))) {
                    $validator->errors()->add("url", 'url unique in site 2');
                }
   }
```