# How to unique validation from multiple tables

Tags: laravel, validation, unique

I want to unique validation a input field from multiple table. But i don't know how to do this. I already try some way but nothing work. Here is my code.

```
$validate = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'gender' => 'required|max:5',
    'email' => 'required|unique:customers,email|unique:subscribers,email|max:128',
]);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501733/laravel-5-multiple-table-unique-validation
Check this link

Comment: I already see this. but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the unique rule twice, like so:

```
$validate = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'gender' => 'required|max:5',
    'email' => 'required|unique:customers|unique:subscribers|max:128',
]);
```

You also don't have to provide the column name, if you leave it unspecified laravel will assume the field name, which is also `email` in this case.